# How to multiply iteratively down a column?

Tags: pandas

I am having a tough time with this one - not sure why...maybe it's the late hour.

I have a dataframe in pandas as follows:

```
1     10
2     11
3     20
4     5
5     10
```

I would like to calculate for each row the multiplicand for each row above it.  For example, at row 3, I would like to calculate 10*11*20, or 2,200.

How do I do this?

Comment: You want a cumulative product.  You can likely achieve this applying a `numpy.cumprod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cumprod](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html).

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 11, 20, 5, 10]}, index=range(1, 6))
df['cprod'] = df['A'].cumprod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, since your example is just a single column, a cumulative product can be done succinctly with a `Series`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([10, 11, 20, 5, 10])
s

# Output
0    10
1    11
2    20
3     5
4    10
dtype: int64

s.cumprod()

# Output
0        10
1       110
2      2200
3     11000
4    110000
dtype: int64
```

Kudos to @bananafish for locating the inherent `cumprod` method.