# Cumulatively applying an operation to successive rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that looks like the following:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame([[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]],
                      index=pd.date_range('2017-08-01','2017-08-04'),
                      columns=['A','B'])

             A   B
2017-08-01   2   3
2017-08-02   4   5
2017-08-03   6   7
2017-08-04   8   9
```

I'd like to cumulatively multiply the values down the columns. Using column `A` as an example, the second row becomes `2*4`, the third row becomes `2*4*6`, and the last row becomes `2*4*6*8`. Same for column B. So, the desired result is:

```
             A    B
2017-08-01   2    3
2017-08-02   8    15
2017-08-03   48   105
2017-08-04   384  945
```

There must be some built-in way to do this, but I'm having issues even doing it with for loops due to chained assignment issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply iteratively down a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218454/how-to-multiply-iteratively-down-a-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html)

```
out = sample.cumprod()
print(out)
              A    B
2017-08-01    2    3
2017-08-02    8   15
2017-08-03   48  105
2017-08-04  384  945
```

---

You can also use [`np.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) on the values:

```
sample[:] = np.cumprod(sample.values, axis=0)
print(sample)
              A    B
2017-08-01    2    3
2017-08-02    8   15
2017-08-03   48  105
2017-08-04  384  945
```

---

Finally, using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (just for fun):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import mul

pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([
                 list(accumulate(sample[c], mul)) for c in sample.columns]), 
             index=sample.index, 
             columns=sample.columns)

              A    B
2017-08-01    2    3
2017-08-02    8   15
2017-08-03   48  105
2017-08-04  384  945
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html):

```
print (sample.cumprod())
              A    B
2017-08-01    2    3
2017-08-02    8   15
2017-08-03   48  105
2017-08-04  384  945
```

Alternative [`numpy.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html):

```
print (np.cumprod(sample))
              A    B
2017-08-01    2    3
2017-08-02    8   15
2017-08-03   48  105
2017-08-04  384  945
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(334)
N = 2000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2], N, p=(0.99, 0.01)),
                   'B':np.random.choice([1,2], N, p=(0.99, 0.01))})
print (df)

In [31]: %timeit (df.cumprod())
The slowest run took 4.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 150 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit (np.cumprod(df))
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit (df.apply(np.cumprod))
The slowest run took 5.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

data frame has a method named `cumprod`. you can use it as follows

```
sample.cumprod()
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve by repeating two already identical answers.

Comment: should i delete it?

Comment: Yes. You should. It adds nothing over the existing answers.

Comment: i was typing it, and when i pressed post answer, it took lot of time to submit.